# Accessing device on local network through server hosted webhook

Tags: python, networking, flask, iot

I have a python script that acts as a webhook. A part of it is as follows:

```
import json
import os
import urllib
import socket
import _thread
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
app=Flask(__name__)

ip = ('192.168.1.75', 9050)

@app.route('/webhook',methods=['GET','POST'])
    def webhook():
        _thread.start_new_thread(sendDataToDevice,(ip))
        req = request.get_json(silent=True,force=True)
        print("Request:")
        print(json.dumps(req,indent=4))
        res=makeWebHookResult(req)
        res=json.dumps(res,indent=4)
        r=make_response(res)
        r.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
        return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080,host='localhost')
```

The function of the script is to send some data to a device connected to the local network.
It works flawlessly when I open my web browser and type the following on the url bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/webhook
```

I want to host the script on a server, eg. Heroku. How can I access the local device in that case?

Note: I know I can run the script on my local machine and make it visible to the internet using ngrok, but I want to keep it accessible even when my computer is switched off. Also, want a fixed link, and the links given by ngrok change on every run.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. In your example you have some device running at `device_ip, device_port = "192.168.1.75", 9050` on your local network. What you want is to be able to get a device_ip and device_port when you host your app on a remote server (e.g. Heroku)?
Also can you tell me what kind of device is this? Is it a computer, smartphone or embedded system?

Comment: That is correct. The device is an embedded system, to be specific, an Arduino Uno board with esp8266 WiFi module.

Comment: Can I assume you have admin access to the WiFi router on your local network?

Comment: Yes, I have admin access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue before with IoT. Unfortunately there is no simple way to make a device be visible online. Here's a simple solution I've used. It might not be the best, but it works.

### DDNS + Port Forwarding + Static IP

If you have access to your local WiFi router, then you can setup something called as DDNS (Dynamic Domain Name System). Your router will then connect to a DDNS service provider like **no-ip** (www.noip.com) and it will be visible on the internet. You can give a custom URL like `susmit-home.noip.com`.

However `susmit-home.noip.com` will now point only to your WiFi router and not your WiFi network. So if you want to access the local `device_ip` and `device_port` such as "192.168.1.75", 9050. Then you can setup Port Forwarding on your router for that local IP-Port combination. Usually the setup looks like this:

- Local IP: `device_ip` (e.g. 192.168.1.75)
- Local Port: `device_port`  (e.g. 9050)
- Outbound Port: `any_port` (e.g. 9050)

Make sure that your `device_ip` is a static IP on your WiFi router so that it doesn't change.

Finally in your code you can just replace the line `ip = ('192.168.1.75', 9050)` with `ip = ('susmit-home.noip.com', 9050)`.

### Other solutions:

1. A slightly more complicated solution is setting up a VPN, such that your local network and your remote server (e.g. Heroku) will all be available to each other as if they were within the same local network.
2. If your device is a computer or a Raspberry Pi, then you can use SSH Remote Port Forwarding to have access to your local device from the remote server.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but I found another workaround. I added a new webhook function to the script. I keep polling it using the device and process the results. This essentially eliminates the need to get the device's IP or port. I'll look into where I went wrong using your method.

Comment: Yep, polling is the most preferred solution even during production :)
An alternate solution that I once tried was keeping the connection always open and dumping results onto the connection. It provides real-time connectivity but it's very unreliable, especially on embedded systems.